# Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1)

Tags: fortran

I am writing a small piece of Fortran 90 code to compute some quantities using complex variables.

I have a subroutine with the following instructions:

```
complex, dimension(3) :: v
integer :: i
real:: tmp


do i = 1,3
  tmp = vg(i)
  v(i) = (tmp, 0.0) 
enddo
```

`v` is a complex array of length 3. `vg` is an array of length 3 too whose elements are real.

When I compile the above code with gfortran 4.7.3 I get the following error:

```
v(i) =   (tmp,0.0) 

Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1)
```

I do not understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
v(i) = cmplx(tmp, 0.0)
```

Your syntax `(re, im)` works only for constant expressions, i.e. when `re` and `im` are real or integer constants.

This means you cannot make a complex constant from a real variable and a real constant. You have to use the intrinsic function `cmplx` which converts `real` variables to `complex` ones, or builds `complex` variables from pairs of `real` variables (or integer).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. When should I use cmplx? In other places I did not use it, e.g.  when initialize v to v = (0.0,0.0). Why in that case the compiler did not complain? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I am doing some operations with complex numbers, should I use result= cmplx(log(v)) or just result = log(v), where v is the variable above defined as v(i) = cmplx(tmp, 0.0)?

Comment: It is because 0.0 is a real constant. You can use `cmplx` everywhere, if you want, it is permitted in initialization expressions.

Comment: In that case you can ommit the conversion function, because the expression on the rhs and the variable on the lhs are both complex. If they were not, default conversion would happen.